# Find string in different word order in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

This might be a pretty basic question but I am hoping someone will be able to help please?

Lets say I have a MySQL table with a field called exampleString which is a text field

In one record, the field exampleString contains the following text :

"apples oranges pears"

Now, what I want to be able to do (PHP) is the following :

1. Perform a query to search for "apples oranges pears" - I can do that, no problem.
2. Perform a query to search for "oranges apples pears" and it will return the record with the string "apples oranges pears" in it - I'm not sure how to do that.  (Note:  If the query search string was just "oranges pears" it shouldn't return the record).

I would also like to be able to make the query case-insensitive and i'm not sure how to do that either (although I haven't searched that yet).

Comment: You can't use `AND` query in loop in php ?
Example : `$string = 'apples oranges pears'; $explode = explode (' ',$string);` and the loop : `foreach($explode as $value) {$query .= 'AND your_field LIKE "%'$value'%"};`  I can answer and explain if it's you need :)

Comment: This isn't what (my)SQL is great at. If you want to use an RDBMS for this, consider normalizing your data. Failing that, consider take a look at FULLTEXT indexes. Otherwise, consider using application level code for this task (my preference).

Comment: Thank you for your replies folks - much appreciated.  I figured that SQL wasn't great at this but wanted to check and you've confirmed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP for loop for each word you have in your input and make your SQL query.

In MySQL, you can use `LIKE "%[your_string]%"` for search a string content [your_string]
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

So, if you need match 'apples oranges pears' and 'apples pears oranges' you need to do something like :

```
LIKE "%apples%" AND LIKE "%oranges%" AND LIKE "%pears%"
```

So you find the string content apples AND oranges AND pears with no order importance

In php now, [the explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) transform a string in array

So, example of final code (adapt clean and secure this for you case. Test your vars etc)

```
$string = 'apples oranges pears';

$explode = explode(' ', $string);

$whereString = '';
foreach ($explode as $key => $value) {
    $whereString .= ' AND [your_field] LIKE "%'.$value.'%"';
}

echo $whereString;
```

Comment: Much appreicated Xenofexs - I figured I would have to do something like this but, not being a MySQL expert I thought I would check to see if it could be done in the query directly.

Comment: It's a pleasure :). Can you check resolved if it's fix your issue ?